# PHP Redirection when error occurs with template system

Tags: php, html, templates, redirect, error-handling

I've a 'template' page which's my 'index.php', it include automatically all the basics stuff like header/footer and in the middle of that : a content page (it's a php script just included).

So, the problem is that when an error is catch in the included script (aka content) it automatically redirect to the original path without all the index stuff (eg. if '/user/login.php' is included and an error occurs, it will automatically redirect to the path of the included file instead of printing it in the index), how can I catch the error directly by the index instead of the script ?

```
<?php require_once('initializer.inc.php'); //need2be here because of session cache limiter warn ?> <html>
<head>
    <?php
        include('head_data.inc.php');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include('header.inc.php');
    ?>

    <?php
    $page = 'index.php';
    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page = 'home.inc.php';
        }
        else
        {
            switch($_GET['page'])
            {
                case '':
                    $page = 'home.inc.php';
                    break;

                /**
                 * USER DEPT
                 */
                case 'connexion':
                    $page = 'utilisateur/connexion.inc.php';
                    break;
                case 'moi':
                    $page = 'utilisateur/moi.inc.php';
                    break;

                case 'mdp-oublie':
                    $page = "utilisateur/mot-de-passe-oublie.php";
                    break;

                case 'gateway':
                    $page = 'utilisateur/gateway.inc.php';
                    break;

                case 'panier':
                    $page = 'utilisateur/panier.inc.php';
                    break;

                /*
                 * PRODUCTS DEPT
                 */
                case 'voir':
                    $page = 'produits/voir.inc.php';
                    break;

                case 'categorie':
                    $page = 'produits/categorie.inc.php';
                    break;

                case 'test': //just for debugging
                    $page = 'test.php';
                    break;

                default:
                    echo '<p>404 Not Found - Cette page n\'existe pas</p>';
            }
        }
        include($page);
    ?>

    <?php
        include('footer.inc.php');
    ?>
 </body>
```

Comment: Well I think it's due to `switch ... case` if I understand correctly you set the page on login so if the user do logs in the `case` is set which will send the user to the path of the set `case`. Why don't you try this in a `if ... else`?

Comment: It's not due to the switch loop, it's not setting the url path, it's just including the file

Comment: Solved : you've to put your index url when posting data eg : 'index.php?page=connexion'